# Initializing services on app startup

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where everything is useless unless the data is fully initialized, so my idea was to create an InitSvc which does the following:

```
myApp.factory('initSvc', function($q, lookupTableSvc, rawDataSvc, consolidatorSvc) {
  $q.wait([lookupTable.load, rawData.load, consolidator.consolidate]);
  // *** Question 1 ***
}
```

lookupTableSvc:

```
myApp.factory('lookupTable', function($q, $http) {
  return {
    load: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer;
      $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'lookupData.js' }).
      success(function (data) {
        this.lookupTable = data;
        $q.resolve();
        // *** Question 2 ***
      })
      return $q.promise;
  };
}
```

rawDataSvc is about the same as lookupTable.

consolidatorSvc should look something like this:

```
myApp.factory('consolidatorSvc', function(rawDataSvc) {
  return {
    consolidate: function() {
      this.dataTable = churn(rawDataSvc.data);
    }
  }
};
```

And finally:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp').
  config(function(initSvc) {
    // *** Question 1 ***
    // set up routes etc
  });

myApp.controller('consolidatedDataCtrl', function(lookupSvc, consolidatorSvc) {
  $scope.lookupValues = lookupSvc.lookupTable; // to get display names
  $scope.dataTable = consolidatorSvc.dataTable;
});

myApp.controller('rawDataCtrl', function(lookupSvc, rawDataSvc) {
  $scope.lookupValues = lookupSvc.lookupTable;
  $scope.data = rawDataSvc.data;
});
```

Question 1:
Will injecting initSvc in module.config automatically cause the config function to pause while it initialzes the data?

Question 2:
Can/should I do $q.resolve() with no arguments since I'm storing the data in another field?

Main question:
I'm just starting angular and have had this app working, but I was doing way too much work in my controller, and the app would crash if someone bookmarked another page other than the start page because the data wasn't initialized. Is this a/the correct way of solving this problem or is there a better way using angular?

The whole application would be easier if I could do some processing server-side, but it will be on a simple static http server.

Comment: The consolidate function should of course return a promise...

Comment: you cannot inject a service ( initSvc ) into config blocks, and you'll get an unknown provider error if you try

Comment: How about in run instead?

Comment: You can inject into a run block, but it won't block the controller from loading.

Comment: Use the resolve feature of your routes, this way you can tell the controllers not to init until the promises in your services have resolved. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve